# How to block rejection through email in approval process?

Tags: approval-process

I have a scenario that approvers can approve the records through email, but they should not 'Reject' through email.

Is it possible to achieve this through standard salesforce functionality? or any other alternative is there?

Thanks,

Comment: A partial solution would be to omit from your 'requesting approval' email template any reference/possibility of a reject action by email. Your email template can direct users to the alternate path in your system should they choose to 'reject'

Comment: I think is the only standard way to avoid rejection.  thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess its either all or none.
If you want users to be able to approve through email then you may not be able to block Rejections through email.

For such customizations, you can check Email Services and see if this works for you. You write your own custom code, and based on the body of the email, you can take decisions through apex code.

Regards,